# Is every left ideal of $M_n (F)[x]$ principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $F$ be a field and $M_n (F)$ the ring of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $F$ and $n>1$. I know that that $F[x]$ is a PID. Trivially, $M_n (F)$ is not commutative and not a field. My question is that is every left ideal of $M_n (F)[x]$ principal?

Comment: Have you tried looking at some left ideals which might not be principal? Like, one generated by say $x$ and some nontrivial left ideal in $M_n(F)$?

Comment: Actually, one should first clarify what a polynomial ring over a matrix ring even is. https://mathoverflow.net/q/50703/27465

Answer (score 0):

We might have better luck with the isomorphic ring $M_n(F[x])$.

In doing a little quick research [I've read that](https://academics.uccs.edu/gabrams/LpasareBezoutforVIASMMay2018%20copy.pdf) Warfield proved that if $R$ is Bezout, then $M_n(R)$ is Bezout.  (I don't have a copy of Warfield's paper to confirm this but regardless $M_n(F)$ is left and right Bezout.)

Since $F[x]$ is Noetherian, so is $M_n(F[x])$ (on both sides.)  That would mean $M_n(F[x])$ is Noetherian and Bezout, hence a principal right and left ideal ring.

---

Just noticed the slides I linked to also suggest such an argument. One can prove that if $R$ is a right principal ideal ring, then so is $M_n(R)$.

Comment: I'm second-guessing myself on $M_n(F[x])\cong M_n(F)[x]$... I don't recall having ever used the idea, but it really feels like the natural maps embedding $M_n(F)\hookrightarrow M_n(F[x])$ and $X\mapsto I_n x$ should give us an isomorphism $M_n(F)[X]\to M_n(F[x])$

Comment: See my comment to the question, cf. https://mathoverflow.net/q/50703/27465

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg For the record, I am interpreting it in the standard way (same as Ben Webster noted in his comment to that question) that "polynomial ring $R[x]$" without further qualification usually means $R$ centralizes $x$.  I realize one can do different things.